# .NET STANDARD 4.7.2 Azure Bearer Token Authorization

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, owin

I have a .NET MVC5/API application that authenticates users via OWIN via Azure. Works great by itself. Users log in using their Azure AD account without issues. I also need to authorize users who have authenticated from the same AD Azure domain, to be able to access this API from other applications. IE Client Application (with an already Azure authorized user) -> this Server application.  My dev client is a Angular application using the MSAL module, that does indeed pass azure bearer tokens in its requests to my .NET API application (seen in Fiddler).  However, the response is always a redirect to microsoft.login to which presents on the client as a CORS error. How can I configure my .NET STANDARD application to authorize users locally via Azure as well as accept already authorized Azure bearer tokens? Also, the client and server applications permissions have been set in Azure (correctly? not 100% on that).

My Startup.Auth:

```
    public partial class Startup
{

    private static string redirectUrl = "Https://" + Settings.RootURL;
    private static string clientId = Settings.GraphClientID;
    private static string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    private static string tenantId = Settings.GraphTenantID;
    private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { CookieName = "CIM-Cookie", SlidingExpiration=true });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from Settings.json
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
            UseTokenLifetime = false, //set to false to manage session with the cookie middleware
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,

            // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            //SignInAsAuthenticationType="Cookies",

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                RoleClaimType = "groups",
                NameClaimType = "name",
            },

            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var emailClaim = identity.Claims.Where(r => r.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    identity.AddClaim(emailClaim);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man. Hours later I found a solution. I added this to my startup.auth:

```
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = "https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxxx",
                Tenant = tenantId
            });
```

I hope this helps someone else someday.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have exposed an api from your server application and added the client application.

[image]

When you get the access token from the client application, please use `api://{client_app_id}/.default` as the scope.

Reference:

[Configure app to expose web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)

[Acquire token for an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token)

Comment: I have all of this set as described. Is there a way to debug from the server side? I wish I could know where exactly its failing.